# How to filter the data using select box in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, filter

i'm new to laravel. my need is search the data using filter from multiple tables... i already done a search box but my colleague need search and we need filter option. i did a ajax script for filter select box but its not working 
my select box id is 
sel_stand
sel_sub
i'm using tables
standards 
sujects
topics

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    jQuery("#sel_stand").add("#sel_sub").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var standard = jQuery("#sel_stand").val();

         jQuery.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getsubjects',
           data:{
            standard:standard
           },
           success:function(data){
              alert(data.users);
              jQuery("#sel_sub").html(data.users);
           }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and this my getsubject Controller

```
   public function getsubjects()

    {
        $input = request()->all();
        //echo $a=request()->standard.request()->subject;
         $users = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `topics` WHERE standard_id='.request()->sel_stand);
         $dta='<option value="">Select Subject</option>';
         foreach ($users as $key => $row){ 
         $dta.='<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->subject_name.'</option>';
         }
         //echo $dta;
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.','users'=>$dta]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what's inside of /getsubjects endpoint (Controller function)? And i'm not sure why you use POST, if it's to GET subjects? Also, please use better formatting in your question.

Comment: kindly checkd it on my question

Comment: May I ask what the value of `jQuery("#sel_stand").val();` may look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function getsubjects(Request $request){
    $users = DB::table('topics')->where('standard_id', $request->standard)->get();
    $dta = '<option value="">Select Subject</option>';
    foreach ($users as $key => $user){ 
        $dta .= '<option value="' . $user->id . '">' . $user->subject_name . '</option>';
    }

    return response()->json(['users' => $dta]);
}
```

But i'd rather suggest to build your options list in JavaScript instead of in PHP.